# Offline upload sales data from SQL to Google Analytics

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I need develop offline uploading sales data to Google Analytics
I need to send data back to google to create revenue attribution models.
I found this example for uploading csv file  :
https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-cost
Maybe there is another way to upload data from SQl Server ?
Can I upload JSON (create uploading process in C# ) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a CSV file (so save it in CSV instead of JSON), then you can create your own system to upload file with Google APIs.

Comment: You're welcome :) mark answer as solved, pls